# How to remove white lines between divs

Tags: html, css

I have images that are distorted in 100x100px squares. I wrote a script to "unscramble" the images, but I can't get rid of the white lines between the divs. When resizing on a laptop, it usually displays ok. On chrome, it looks fine. On Firefox, I get some grid lines. But on mobile and iPad, It's very inconsistent. I've tried several different suggestions from various slack posts, but none have worked so far. There are no spaces between the divs, the divs are floated left, tried display: block, font-size: 0, overflow: hidden, clear: none, using -1px margin and +1px padding. What else can I do to completely get rid of these lines?

```js
function imageStitch() {
  let sBodyMargin = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('margin-right');
  const BODY_MARGINS = sBodyMargin.substring(0, sBodyMargin.length - 2) * 2;
  
  function init() {
    let imageStitch = document.getElementsByClassName('image-stitch');
    if (imageStitch != null) {
      // Add event listener
      window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
      // Loop through pages of images and unscramble them
      let pages = document.getElementsByClassName('scrambled');
      for (page of pages) {
        unscramble(page);
      }
    }
  }
  
  function unscramble(page) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = page.getAttribute('data-image-url');
    
    $(image).on('load', function() {
      page.setAttribute("imageWidth", image.width);
      page.setAttribute("imageHeight", image.height);
      // Images are in 100x100px squares
      // Last row and column may be smaller than 100px
      let maxRows = Math.ceil(image.height / 100);
      let maxCols = Math.ceil(image.width / 100);
      
      // Page CSS
      page.style.maxWidth = image.width + "px";
      page.style.margin = "auto";
      page.style.position = "relative";
      
      for (let r = 1; r <= maxRows; r++) {
        // Create row div with classes
        let rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
        rowDiv.classList.add("row", "r" + r);

        // row CSS
        rowDiv.style.display = "flex";
        rowDiv.style.flexDirection = "row";

        for (let c = 1; c <= maxCols; c++) {
          // Create column div and add classes
          let colDiv = document.createElement("div");
          colDiv.classList.add("col", "c" + c);

          let colWidth = c < maxCols ? 10000 / image.width : ((image.width % 100) / image.width) * 100;
          let colHeight = r < maxRows ? 10000 / image.width : ((image.height % 100) / image.width) * 100;
          let backgroundSize = c < maxCols ? image.width : 10000 / colWidth;
          let xPosition = c < maxCols ? (c - 1) * (10000 / (image.width - 100)) : 100;
          let yPosition = r < maxRows ? (r - 1) * (10000 / (image.height - 100)) : 100;

          // column CSS
          colDiv.style.float = "left";
          colDiv.style.width = colWidth + "%";
          colDiv.style.paddingTop = colHeight + "%";
          colDiv.style.backgroundSize = backgroundSize + "%";
          colDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + page.getAttribute("data-image-url") + ")";
          colDiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
          colDiv.style.backgroundPosition = xPosition + "% " + yPosition + "%";
          colDiv.style.transform = r % 2 != 0 ? "scaleX(-1)" : "scaleX(-1) scaleY(-1)";

          // Append column to row
          rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);
        }
        // Append row to page
        page.appendChild(rowDiv);
      }
      resize();
    });
  }
  
  function resize() {
    let pages = document.getElementsByClassName("scrambled");
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth - BODY_MARGINS;
    for (page of pages) {
      let imageWidth = page.getAttribute("imageWidth");
      if (screenWidth < imageWidth) {
        let columns = imageWidth / 100;
        page.style.width = Math.floor(screenWidth / columns) * columns + "px";
      } else {
        page.style.width = page.style.maxWidth;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return {
    init: init
  }
}

imageStitch().init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-stitch">
  <div data-image-url="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1olgv-FJMOICxQrly4iBZXYAIHUU2w5WU" class="scrambled"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using javascript to post images while there is a more universal way of using css, which is less complicated and you will get better results throughout browsers?

Comment: @Mugé a friend is having problems with images being stolen from their site. Using javascript, the images won't load at all if they try to turn off js to swipe the images. If you have an easier solution to stealing images, I'm all ears.

Comment: There are a number of ways to play around with images, so they do not get stolen, however, you also do not want to make your site user unfriendly because you are afraid someone will use your image. I came to senses that someone stealing your image probably liked it a lot.

Comment: Sorry I am going on, but tell your friend, if s/he comes across his/her image at some website, they can contact them ask to be removed or consequences.  Next step, there is Google or some other private companies that take care of copyrighted material.

Comment: I do not think these comments offer anything but speculation on an individual's proposed actions and therefore do not answer the question.

Comment: On a side note, I popped your code into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pd5jfreu/) and can't seem to see the issue you're having? Could you provide a link to where you're facing this issue?

Comment: As EGC commented, I did not see anything on Moz either, but OP has a diagram image posted, so I take that as a lead to a problem.

Comment: @EGC you can see the problem in the image above.  My code pen is codepen.io/jojobean13/pen/QWwKdOv. You can probably see it if you access the codepen from your phone. On laptop, it displays fine for the most part. I'm using Chrome. Haven't really tested other browsers yet.